# Report Viewer C# data from Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to do my Report. To generate the report my steps are:

1. Use report viewer
2. Connect database (ACCESS)
3. Successfully generate my report

The issue I'm facing right now is that I want my report to show according to a specific date which I need to enter into the textbox or by using a timepicker. I've been searching for YouTube tutorials and tried using an SQL statement in the Table Adapter. The code I wrote is:

```
(WHERE abx_date= [Forms]![Form1]![searchTextBox] )
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `[Forms]![Form1]![searchTextBox]![Text]`.

Comment: @waka tried. It appeared "Error in WHERE clause near "!"". Unable to parse query text.